# which.max() returning repeated index number

Tags: r

When I run the following code:

```
library(MASS)
attach(Boston)
lm.fit=lm(medv~lstat)
which.max(hatvalues(lm.fit))
```

It returns:

```
375
375
```

Why does it repeat itself and return 375 twice?

Comment: unsolicited advice: it's better practice to use `lm.fit=lm(medv~lstat,data=Boston)` rather than `attach()` ...

Answer (score 4):

It's not repeating itself, instead, that is the name that `which.max` has assigned. Check out the `str` of the object:

```
library(MASS)
attach(Boston)
lm.fit=lm(medv~lstat)
(f1 <- which.max(hatvalues(lm.fit)))

375 
375 

str(f1)

 Named int 375
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "375"
```